# Date Time formatting in Windows 10 Universals (Store) Apps

Tags: xaml, localization, windows-10-universal

When I write a universal Windows 10 (UWP) app date-time formatting is English (as the "default language" off the app is en-US).
I can change this - then it is some different formatting.
I want this formatting to be the same as the installed (current) Windows 10 language.

In WPF this was easy - just set

```
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

I know that I can support other languages by adding resource files to the app.
But this results in the requirement to provide "app descriptions" and so forth in the store.

My approach is (for an example) to build an app that just supports English - but with "current locale matching" Date / Time / Number displays (inputs).

I also know that I can work with

```
Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.Languages[0];
```

as base for `CultureInfo` object...

But that would break "simple bindings" for such values.

Is there a way to get the same behavior like formerly in WPF?

Comment: Could you use `DateTime.Now.ToString("your date time format", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture)` or read this topic https://www.pedrolamas.com/2015/11/02/cultureinfo-changes-in-uwp/

Comment: This is what I showed in my second snippet. But what I need is binding. Thank you for the link - it exactly highlights the problem I have.