# Get actual system culture info

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I have an UWP app for Windows 10 Mobile. The app currently offers two languages - English (`en-US`) and Czech (`cs-CZ`). The issue I'm having is that when a user for example from Spain uses the app, the date and time formats are American, not Spanish (the default app language is `en-US`):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("d", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
DateTime.Now.ToString("d", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
DateTime.Now.ToString(System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern);
```

I would like to somehow obtain the ACTUAL system language to have the dates and times in the correct format based on the phone language. Currently, it looks like all the APIs from `System.Globalization` namespace return the culture info the app is using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more searching, I've managed to come across the following question: [Date Time formatting in Windows 10 Universals (Store) Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35512939/date-time-formating-in-windows-10-univerals-store-apps) where the author of the question mentions the following API call:

```
Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.Languages[0]
```

This returns the language string for the first language from the user's system preferences language list.

Using it in the following way gives me the expected result:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("d", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.Languages[0]));
```

Comment: This fails on systems, where the preferred language and the preferred locale are not the same. You are constructing a `CultureInfo` object based on the user's preferred language, not on the user's preferred date and time format.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you for your observation! I've done some research and, unfortunately, there doesn't seem to exist any API for that. And even the UWP `DatePicker` and `TimePicker` use formats based on the first system language, not the preferred format. So this is consistent with the rest of the system behavior.

Comment: Still, though, some applications get the regional settings right. I'm not versed enough in UWP development to know, whether there is a dedicated (yet well hidden) API, or whether those apps simply go to lengths to evaluate/guess the desired regional settings.